# move element across page with smooth move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move a cockroach through the whole page in a logical and real way.

I wrote this code but it's not working in a good status.
This code is not logical, just put it for clarification
I want his movement to be logical so that he goes through the whole page, to be flexible for all screens
Can anybody help, please?`

```js
 $(function(){
 var x = $(".container"); 
    
     setTimeout(function() {
    x.addClass("first");   
  }, 1000);
  
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(x).children().css({transition : "2s"});
                $(x).css({transition : "4s"});
    x.addClass("second"); 
  }, 2000);
    
    
    setTimeout(function() {
          $(x).children().css({transition : "0s"});
                $(x).css({transition : "0s"});
    x.addClass("third"); 
  }, 4000);
    
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(x).children().css({transition : "4s"});
                $(x).css({transition : "2s"});
    x.addClass("fourth"); 
  }, 6000);
  
       setTimeout(function() { 
          $(x).children().css({transition : "2s"});
                $(x).css({transition : "3s"});
    x.addClass("fifth"); 
  }, 8000);
})
```

```css
.container{
        position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    transition: transform 1s;
   
}
.container.first{
    transform: translateX(200px) ;
    
}
img{
    width:60px;
    height: 60px;
    
    border-radius: 2px;

    transition: transform 2s;
}
 
.container.first img{
     transform: translateY(-100px) rotate(-50deg);
}
  
.container.first.second img{
     transform: translateY(-200px) rotate(-135deg);
}
.container.first.second{
    transform: translateX(-200px) ;
    
}
 
.container.first.second.third img{
     transform:translateX(-20px) translateY(-250px) rotate(30deg) ;
}
.container.first.second.third{
    transform: translateX(-50px) scale(1 , 1.6);
    
}  

.container.first.second.third.fourth img{
     transform: translateY(-450px) rotate(-55deg);
}
.container.first.second.third.fourth{
    transform: translateX(400px) ;
    
}


.container.first.second.third.fourth.fifth img{
     transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(-90deg);
}
.container.first.second.third.fourth.fifth{
    transform: translateX(250px) ;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/drkathyobear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/cockroach.jpg" />  
    </div>
```

`

Comment: Do you mean random path? Currently your logic is following the same path

Comment: It's not exactly clear what it is you want. What do you mean by "logical"? Do you want the movement to be random but to remain within the window? A bit more information would help

Comment: random path or same path  , i don't care @Rohit.007

Comment: i want move it  smoothly across the page, Whether it is random or not @MichaelBeeson